# Get last 25 days low from STOCKHISTORY function in MS Excel

Tags: excel, office365

I tried below function to get the low price of Ticker but it return 60 row. I want 25 days low.

`=INDEX(SORT(STOCKHISTORY(A235,TODAY()-60,TODAY(),0,0,0,4),1,-1), 0,2)`

Comment: Then wouldn't you want `TODAY()-25` instead of `TODAY()-60`?

Comment: @ScottCraner it calculates days based on date not stock trading session. If I make it 25 it will return me last 10 or 11 trading session lows.

Comment: Then you should show an example of the data so your problem is clear.

Comment: then use: `WORKDAY.INTL(TODAY(),-25,,holidays)` where `holidays` is a range reference with the holidays that are not on the weekends.  And then you can get rid of the INDEX() wrapper.

Comment: or change the `, 0,` to `, SEQUENCE(25),`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. ```SEQUENCE(25)``` worked. Please give solution as answer.